# Subtracting Single array values

Tags: swift

I have an array-like [70, 71, 72, 80, 90, 100, 120] . I want to find the difference like [71-70] = 1,[72-71]= 1,[80-72]= 2 So on and save difference  in Array . Please help me . Thanks  in advance

Comment: Please some code that you have tried.

Comment: i am not using code i have no idea what can I do

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Assuming we have the following extention that breaks an Array into the array of pairs

```
extension Array {
    func chunked() -> [[Element]] {
        return stride(from: 0, to: count-1, by: 1).map {
            Array(self[$0 ..< Swift.min($0 + 2, count)])
        }
    }
}
```

we can now just map our original array and flatten the portions

```
let array = [70, 71, 72, 80, 90, 100, 120]

var array2 = array.chunked()
print(array2)
// prints [[70, 71], [71, 72], [72, 80], [80, 90], [90, 100], [100, 120]]

let array3 = array2.map { $0[1] - $0[0]  }
print(array3)
// prints [1, 1, 8, 10, 10, 20]
```

or just like this

```
let diffs = array.chunked().map { $0[1] - $0[0] }
print(diffs)
// prints [1, 1, 8, 10, 10, 20]
```

Answer (score -1):

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array

Multiple ways to solve this question:

1. **A simple for Loop:**

```
let array = [70, 71, 72, 80, 90, 100, 120]
var diffArray: [Int] = []

// another initializer for array is:
// var diffArray: [Int] = [Int](repeating: 0, count: array.count - 1) 

for i in 1..<array.count {
    diffArray.append(array[i] - array[i-1])
}
```

2. **Reduce:** Allows you to modify the array into something you can use, do some calculation and return data as per your requirement.

```
let array = [70, 71, 72, 80, 90, 100, 120]
var diffArray = array.reduce([Int]()) { partialDiff, next in
    var partialDiff = partialDiff
    if partialDiff.count != 0 {
        partialDiff[partialDiff.count - 1] = next - partialDiff[partialDiff.count - 1] 
    }
    partialDiff.append(next)
    return partialDiff
}
diffArray.popLast()
```

The second approach is not really an optimal approach in this scenario. Just to show what you can do with `reduce`. **Approach 1** should solve your problem

Comment: Person should try himself, otherwise he wuill never be able to do something, he will always wait for tips

Comment: I agree, this was a very basic problem.

Comment: basic problem is okay, but he didnt even try to do it himself. This is "do it for me" type of questions and for the sake of the person better to avoid write ready-made code otherwise his own ability to learn will never evolve